# Can we use Nvidia graphic card in apple M1 pro laptop

Tags: nvidia, apple-m1, video-card

Does Apple m1 pro support the Integrated Graphics Nvidia?It has its own Apple GPU?Can we use Integrated Graphics Nvidia in Apple m1 pro instead of its own Apple GPU?

[image]

Does Apple m1 pro support the Dedicated Graphics Card Nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Apple m1 pro support the Integrated Graphics Nvidia?

No. The integrated graphics on M1/M2 are Apple not nVidia.

> It has its own Apple GPU?

Yes

> Can we use Integrated Graphics Nvidia in Apple m1 pro instead of its
> own Apple GPU?

No

> Does Apple m1 pro support the Dedicated Graphics Card Nvidia?

Likely no. It’s possible to add a Thunderbolt 4 pcie slot. I’m unaware of any nVidia drivers for the Apple M1.